# Modify AD Attribue for a specified list of users

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2003, ldap, ldif

How would you modify a set of AD attributes for a specified list of users? In particular, I would like to set the following for individual users since the exchange general tab under user properties with Active Directory Users and Computers limits the size to 2^21 kB (2GB).

```
mDBStorageQuota
mDBOverQuotaLimit
mDBOverHardQuotaLimit
```

If the answer is ldifde, I could use a couple examples / spoonfeeding ... Also, would it just be modify, or does that attribute not exist until it is defined?

Answer (score 1):

Copying from another post (which I can't link to as a new user, just search for Admodify)

[Admodify.NET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996216%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) from Microsoft is your friend. You should be able to use the attribute fuction to set those three properties.

(Again, I tried to include a screenshot but couldn't, its the first image on the MSDN page)

This can also be done in powershell if you are running exchange 2007, but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally use some VBScript for this, plenty of examples on the web, but something like this is what you want:

```
Set objUser = GetObject ("LDAP://cn=joeheadbanger,ou=blah,dc=mycompany,dc=com")
objUser.mDBStorageQuota = 666
objUser.SetInfo
```

Test on an unimportant account first, of course.